# Can I curry this better?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, currying, ramda.js

I've made this snippet using `ramda` to check if any value of array A exists in array B, assuming they are flat arrays.

```
var hasAtLeastOneTruthValue = ramda.contains(true);
var alpha = [1,2,3]
var beta = [4,1,7];

var valueOfArrayInArray = ramda.map(function(a_v){
    return ramda.contains(a_v, beta);
});

console.log(hasAtLeastOneTruthValue(valueOfArrayInArray(alpha)));
```

What I do not like is that *hardcoded* `beta` inside `valueOfArrayInArray`. Can it be done differently so that it's not? Please note that I'm not looking for a completely different implementation that has the same effect, but simply to understand currying better in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could partially apply `contains` from the right:

```
var valueOfArrayInArray = R.map(R.rPartial(R.contains, beta))
```

Or flip it:

```
var valueOfArrayInArray = R.map(R.flip(R.contains)(beta))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use binding:

```
var hasAtLeastOneTruthValue = ramda.contains(true);

var alpha = [1,2,3]
var beta = [4,1,7];

function finder(lookup,a_v){
    return ramda.contains(a_v, lookup);
}

var valueOfArrayInArray = ramda.map(finder.bind(null,beta));

console.log(hasAtLeastOneTruthValue(valueOfArrayInArray(alpha)));
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! This is a working solution but @elclanrs 's is more "functional" which is what I am trying to get fluent at, so I'm accepting his.